# $\Sigma \mathbb{R}P^n$ and $S^2 \vee S^3 \vee ... \vee S^{n+1}$ are not homotopy equivalent

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, fundamental-groups

I want to use all the material for my algebraic topology class since I'm quite lost in it...
For that, I want to show that $\Sigma \mathbb{R}P^n$ and $S^2 \vee S^3 \vee ... \vee S^{n+1}$ are not homotopy equivalent using different technique I learned. I wanted to use the fundamental group, cohomology with integral coefficients, and the Bockstein
homomorphism.

1. For the fundamental group I know that it is trivial for $S^2 \vee S^3 \vee ... \vee S^{n+1}$ but I don't know how the second one look like...
2. for cohomology with integral coefficient, I guess I should use the fact that suspension have trivial cup products but then I'm stuck
3. I find the bockstein homomorphism really hard to understand so I don't know where to start here...

I quite lost and I've read my class note so many times, so maybe some hints would help a lot!

Comment: It's bad form to edit a question after an answer has been posted, especially if your edit makes it so that the existing answer seems to no longer be on topic.

Comment: Anyway, all of the cup products are trivial for both spaces, as has been addressed elsewhere. Feel free to ask a separate question if you understand the case for the cohomology ring of $X_1 \vee X_2$ but not for more than two summands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their homology groups with $\mathbb{Z}$-coefficients are different. Same for cohomology. (As long as $n>1$ — if $n=1$, the spaces are homeomorphic.)